# Solving trigonometry equations from graphs when transformations (e.g. $3\tan^2$) are involved?

Tags: trigonometry

**Preface; I'm not asking for answers (that won't help me learn Maths at all!), but certainly some guidance would be very much appreciated.**

I'm trying to solve some trigonometry equations from graphs, and it's all going fine; until transformations are involved.

I'm aware that a number before the $\tan,\sin,\cos$ (e.g. $3\cos$) 'compresses' the graph by a scale factor of said number. But what if there is a squared sign infront of it as well?

Example equations which I'm struggling with -
$$\cos^2(x) = 3/4$$
$$3\tan^2(x) = 1$$

Certainly with the first one, I'm in a mess already because 3/4 doesn't appear in the common trignometry values (http://www.analyzemath.com/trigonometry/special_angles_1.gif).

Thanks for reading,
Cameron.

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you aware that $\cos^2(x)$ means $(\cos(x))^2$, and likewise for other trigonomatric functions?

Answer (score 2):

If your question appears in exercises that do not require the use of a calculator, it is almost certain that only special angles will be needed. For the two cases you mentioned, simply manipulate the equations until you get the familiar "trigo function = something" and solve it.

For instance,

1. suppose that $\cos^2(x) = 3/4$.
2. Let $C = \cos(x)$; the equation then becomes $C^2 = 3/4$.
3. Solve for $C$; $C = -\sqrt{3}/2$ or $\sqrt{3}/2$.
4. Look at the equation again: $\cos(x) = -\sqrt{3}/2$ or $\sqrt{3}/2$.

So, simply "peel off" everything from the trigonometric function and make it the subject, then see if the other side of the equation corresponds to a special angle.

If $\cos^2(x) = 3/4$, then $\cos(x) = \pm\sqrt{3}/2$, which corresponds to a special angle.

If $3\tan^2(x) = 1$, then $\tan(x) = \pm1/\sqrt 3$, which corresponds to the same special angle.